# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/regex.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following error when i build my code using regex.hpp I am using VS2010 VC++

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/regex.hpp': No such file or directory

boost\boost_regex-vc71-mt-1_33_1.lib file is here.. is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your include settings do not have the path to the boost installation parent directory.

Look at these instructions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide

and note especially the include directory setup.

Comment: After doing this i am getting Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\test.pch': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have included the path to the Boost header files in Visual C++.

Follow the instructions [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28VS.71%29.aspx)

This issue arises because Visual C++ does not include the path to the Boost header files. By including the directory, Visual C++ will search that directory for the problem and hopefully your problem should be solved.

Comment: Also this should be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288739%28VS.71%29.aspx#boostvc_topic8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error message is true? The file is not there?

Comment: boost\boost_regex-vc71-mt-1_33_1.lib file is here.. is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Ubuntu, install the boost library with synaptic, including the regex package. It is not enough with downloading from the boost website and building the regex library in the computer (instructions in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html), additionally you have to download it with synaptic. I guess this second redundant step is neccessary because synaptic may update some system variables (the $PATH???) and install some other dependencies that a direct download from [www.boost.org](http://www.boost.org) does not do.